# Failed to trigger pipeline Jenkins build from Bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, devops

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with Bitbucket. For this thing, i have installed on the Jenkins the Bitbucket plugin. In the Bitbucket, i have defined a WebHook. Now i want when a new commit is made in a branch, the Jenkins job to be automatically triggered. But this thing is not working, even if the webhook seems to work and the response is 200.

My webhook:
[image]

Jenkins configuration:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What webhook was defined in Bitbucket? Why does the webhook seem to work?  If it worked, what does your Jenkins job build output say?

Comment: your pipeline specifies a branch selector /new_master. Is this definately the branch you're committing/merging code into ? (i.e you're not inadvertaintly checking code into /master or some other feature branch.